# void linux and locking screen on suspend

Tags: suspend, hibernate, screen-lock, void-linux

I have some troubles with using slock with void linux.
I tried adding slock as a script to zzz: `/etc/zzz.d/suspend/slock`

```
#!/bin/sh
slock
```

which works in a strange way: if I call `zzz`, it brings up slock and doesn't suspend until I enter my password and unlock. I moved the script to `/etc/zzz.d/resume/slock`, now on resume it flashes unlocked screen for a second and then locks the screen, which is not so good but fine.

But there is another problem: closing the lid suspends the laptop but it doesn't lock the screen at all.
I thought it might have something to do with `acpid`. When I disable `acpid`, closing lid doesn't suspend the laptop, so `acpid` is definitely responsible for this. I tried to tinker with `/etc/acpi/handler.sh`, now it looks like this:

```
                close)
                        # suspend-to-ram
                        logger "LID closed, suspending..."
                        slock
                        zzz
                        ;;
                open)   logger "LID opened" ;;
                *) logger "ACPI action undefined (LID): $2";;
```

and `slock` is not executed anyways. I tried removing `zzz` from `handler.sh`, then closing the lid doesn't do anything, which means it actually executes `zzz` when it's present but doesn't execute `zzz`'s user scripts for some reason. I also tried replacing `slock` with `i3lock` in both `handler.sh` (like void [wiki](https://wiki.voidlinux.org/Acpi#Locking_the_screen_on_lid_close) suggests) and `zzz.d/resume` but it's the same. Did I do something wrong or is there another reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Tinkered this issue like this:

/etc/zzz.d/suspend/01

```
#!/bin/sh
doas -u ds xsecurelock &
sleep 2
```

/etc/doas.conf

```
permit persist :wheel
permit nopass root as ds cmd xsecurelock
permit nopass :wheel as root cmd zzz
permit nopass :wheel as root cmd ZZZ
permit nopass keepenv root as root
```

You can try to define $DISPLAY for root user in suspend script, but I'm too stupid to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial solution does not work because the shell waits for the slock process to stop before continuing. The easiest (but not best) solution to to make the command `slock &` which allows processes to continue after. However, this does not guarentee slock will finish running before the device suspends.

The "proper" way to do this would be using `xss-lock` to call slock, and using `xset` to lock the screen on command. Both of these can be found in Void's repositories. `xss-lock slock` would set xss-lock to use slock for locking.

This *should* work without any additional scripts, as xss-lock is supposed to act on suspend normally. However, suspend-based events have always been buggy, so an additional activation through xset isn't a bad idea.

An example `/etc/zzz.d/suspend/slock` would be

```
#!/bin/sh
xset s activate
```

A similar script could be placed in the respective "resume" file, but the previous issue of an unlocked screen showing up before the lock screen would still appear.